# SQL WHERE = BUT check each value from list

Tags: mysql

I have a table that houses the name of the game and when the user how long the user played it for. I able to work out how long all the users played one game for

```
select game, sum((timeplayedval)/60/24) as total_days_play_time FROM (
SELECT * from Messages.games 
WHERE type = "Ended"
&& game = "Fortnite" -- for [list, of, other,games]
&& NOT timeplayedval = null
&& NOT timeplayedval < 2 
&& NOT timeplayedval > 1440
) as t
```

but would like to be able to do the same for the rest of the games in the list. 
Have them displaced as bellow. 
`[{game:"gamename0", timeplayed: number},{game:gamename1, timeplayed: number}]`

Thanks

Comment: Some notes: Double quotes are for names. Use single quotes for string literals. `&&` is non-standard and makes it harder for others to understand your query. Use standard `AND` instead. Never use `=` with `NULL`; use `IS NULL` (or `IS NOT NULL`).

Comment: I was stupid when I made the table as null is a string. I did't want you to know xD

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in line 4 should do it.

```
&& game in ("Fortnite", "Game2", "Game3")
```

and then add this at the bottom

```
group by game
```

Comment: That's what I thought. How would display I pass the gamename back to the select above –

Comment: Edited my post to make the query group by game name.

Comment: Won't this fail because of using the double quotes around string literals?

Answer (score 0):

Use an IN clause   for the list of game, use for multiple condition related to timeplayedval  and use group by for column in select not involved in aggreagtion function

```
    select game, sum((timeplayedval)/60/24) as total_days_play_time FROM (
        SELECT * from Messages.games 
        WHERE type = "Ended"
        AND  game IN ("Fortnite", "other","games")
        AND (  NOT timeplayedval IS  null OR   NOT timeplayedval < 2 
        OR NOT timeplayedval > 1440 ) 
    ) as t
    group by game
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a result row per game, so group by game:

```
select
  game, 
  SUM(timeplayedval) / 60 / 24 AS total_days_play_time 
FROM Messages.games 
WHERE type = 'Ended'
AND game IN ('Fortnite', 'Other Game', ...)
AND timeplayedval BETWEEN 2 AND 1440
GROUP BY game,
ORDER BY game;
```